# Deep Arrays and hashes for humans to read

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How it is possible to get beautifuly formatted Array and Hash on rails for human to read?

I got answer from PayPal payment with different deep arrays inside and I can't understand where is primary arrays, where is params and so on. I got result in one line, plus with some `<Paypal::Payment::Common::Amount:0x00000005aty4e458` codes - which makes output imposible to read where is which var, so I want to get in:

```
var=>{v=1, v=2, v={1,1}},
var2=>{b=4}
```

and so on, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at awesome_print - https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

Available as a gem - https://rubygems.org/gems/awesome_print/versions/1.6.1